# Join N copies of a snippet to produce N^2 characters

Tags: code-golf, quine, source-layout

## Challenge

Write the shortest snippet of code possible such that, when N copies of it are concatenated together, the number of characters output is N<sup>2</sup>. N will be a positive integer.

For example if the snippet was `soln();`, then running `soln();` would print exactly 1 character, and running `soln();soln();` would print exactly 4 characters, and running `soln();soln();soln();` would print exactly 9 characters, etc.

Any characters may be in the output as long as the total number of characters is correct. To avoid cross-OS confusion, `\r\n` newlines are counted as one character.

**Programs may not read their own source or read their file size or use other such loopholes.** Treat this like a strict [quine](/questions/tagged/quine) challenge.

The output may go to stdout or a file or a similar alternative. There is no input.

Comments in the code are fine, as is exiting mid-execution.

Any characters may be in the program. The shortest submission [in bytes](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter) wins.

Comment: Does the program have to terminate?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yes

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## TECO, 4 bytes

```
V1\V
```

`V` prints the contents of the current line in the text buffer. `1\` inserts the string representation of the number 1 at the current position.

So on the *N*th iteration of the program, the first `V` will output *N - 1* copies of the character `1`, then add another `1` to the text, then output *N* `1`s.

Comment: Can you add a link to TECO?

Answer (score 22):

## Brainfuck, <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
[>+>-..+<<-]-.>+
```

You can test it [here](http://copy.sh/brainfuck/). Just use the fact that `n2+2n+1=(n+1)2`.

Comment: I can't believe I'm seeing BF at a competitive level of bytes!

Answer (score 22):

## Brainfuck, 11

I saw the first Brainfuck answer and thought it's way too long :)

```
[.<]>[.>]+.
```

The output may be easier to see if you replace the plus with a lot more pluses.

On the Nth iteration, each loop outputs N - 1 copies of the character with ASCII value 1, and then one more with `+.`.

Comment: You need to print N^2 characters, not N characters.  I can't read BF code, so I don't know if your code is incorrect or if your description is incorrect.

Comment: @BrianJ It prints N^2 characters. You can test it here: http://copy.sh/brainfuck/ Replace the plus with a minus if you can't see the output.

Comment: @alephalpha Oops, I now see that I misread the comment.  The code does not do (N - 1) + 1 like I originally thought.

Answer (score 16):

## Python 2, 22

```python
a='';print a;a+='xx';a
```

Prints the empty string, then two `x`'s, then `x`' four and so on. With the newline after each string, this comes out to `n*n` characters.

One copy: `"\n"` (1 char)
Two copies: `"\nxx\n"` (4 chars)
Three copies:  `"\nxx\nxxxx\n"` (9 chars)

In order to stop the initial variable `a` from being reinitialized each run, I end the code with a `;a`, which is benign on its own, but combined with the next loop to create the scapegoat `aa` to be assigned instead. This trick isn't mine; I saw it in a previous answer. I'd appreciate if someone could point me so I could give credit.

Comment: Actually, is the final newline printed?

Comment: no I don't think the final newline is printed. But simply removing the `,` after `print a` should work. `print a` prints a newline after each print.

Comment: @Quincunx Oh, of course, thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about [this post](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/35666/21487)?

Answer (score 10):

## CJam, 6 bytes

```
LLS+:L
```

Uses the fact that `n2 + n + (n+1) = (n+1)2`.

```
L      "Push L. Initially this is an empty string, but its length increases by 1 with each copy
        of the snippet.";
 L     "Push another L.";
  S+   "Add a space to the second copy.";
    :L "Store the lengthened string in L for the next copy of the snippet.";
```

Comment: `:L..1+` is the same idea in GolfScript.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I was thinking `..n+` in GolfScript, but that pesky trailing newline... :(

Comment: Hah, you're right. No need for `:L` because it's not used.

Answer (score 10):

## [///](http://esolangs.org/wiki////), 21 bytes

I'm sure there is a really short and twisted way to solve this in **///** but I couldn't find anything, beyond the "straightforward" way yet:

```
1/1\//112\///2\//1\//
```

This is based on the approach of printing consecutive odd numbers. The snippet consists of a `1` at the start which is printed, and two replacements which add two more `1`s to that first part of each consecutive copy of the snippet. Let's go through this for `N = 3`. The following should be read in groups of 3 or more lines: 1. the current code, 2. the processed token(s), 3. (and following) a comment what the above token does.

```
1/1\//112\///2\//1\//1/1\//112\///2\//1\//1/1\//112\///2\//1\//
1
is printed
/1\//112\///2\//1\//1/1\//112\///2\//1\//1/1\//112\///2\//1\//
/1\//112\//
replaces all occurrences of 1/ with 112/. This affects the starts of all further snippets
but not the substitution commands, because the slashes in those are always escaped.
It is necessary to put a 2 in there, because otherwise the interpreter goes into an infinite
loop replacing the resulting 1/ again and again.
/2\//1\//112/1\//112\///2\//1\//112/1\//112\///2\//1\//
/2\//1\//
Replace all occurrences of 2/ with 1/, so the the next snippets substitution works again.
111/1\//112\///2\//1\//111/1\//112\///2\//1\//
111
is printed
/1\//112\///2\//1\//111/1\//112\///2\//1\//
/1\//112\//
add two 1s again
/2\//1\//11112/1\//112\///2\//1\//
/2\//1\//
turn the 2 into a 1 again
11111/1\//112\///2\//1\//
11111
print 11111
/1\//112\///2\//1\//
the last two substitutions have nothing to substitute so they do nothing
```

Interestingly, it works just as well if we move the `1` to the end:

```
/1\//112\///2\//1\//1
```

Answer (score 7):

## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 14 bytes

```
1:na*a*';'10p!
```

Uses the "sum of consecutive odd integers starting from 1" idea. It starts off with 1 and multiplies it by 100 each time, increasing the length of the output progressively by increments of 2.

For example, appending 5 copies gives

```
1100100001000000100000000
```

I tested by piping the output to a file, and didn't see a trailing newline.

### Breakdown

```
1                   Push 1, skipped by ! every time except the first
 :n                 Copy top of stack and output as num                  
   a*a*             Multiply by 10 twice
       ';'10p       Modify the source code so that the first : becomes a ; for termination
             !      Skip the next 1
```

Answer (score 5):

## CJam, <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
],)_S*a*~
```

This prints N<sup>2</sup> spaces where `N` is the number of copies of the code.

**Code eexpansion**:

```
],            "Wrap everything on stack and take length";
  )_          "Increment and take copy";
    S*        "Get that length space string";
      a*      "Wrap that space string in an array and create that many copies";
        ~     "Unwrap so that next code can use to get length";
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, 20 bytes

```
g=0
print'g'*g;g+=2#
```

Answer (score 5):

## Java - 91 bytes

```
{String s=System.getProperty("a","");System.out.println(s);System.setProperty("a","xx"+s);}
```

This solution is equivalent to [this other one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/45381) in Python. It surely won't win, but it was fun :)

Comment: Don't you need a class to run anything?

Comment: No, since OP asked for snippets of code. We can assume this is running inside a main, for example.

Comment: Then I have a 59 or even 44 byte solution.

Comment: Cool :) I prefer one-liners, but yours is indeed shorter!

Answer (score 4):

### Perl, 14 bytes

```pl
print;s//__/;
```

This needs to be run with Perl's `-l` command switch, which causes `print` to append new lines.

It prints the default variable `$_`, then prepends two underscores via substitution.

Example:

```
$ perl -le 'print;s//__/;print;s//__/;print;s//__/;print;s//__/;'

__
____
______
```

Comment: flags are counted as 1 more byte per flag

Comment: What about `say`?

Comment: @chilemagic I tried that, but I couldn't get it working on my versions of Perl.

Comment: @grc it's version 5.10 and higher and you need `-E` instead.

Comment: @chilemagic hmm, that didn't seem to work for me on 5.16.

Comment: @grc that's really odd. I just tested it on 5.14 in cygwin `perl -E 'say;s//__/;say;s//__/;say;s//__/;say;s//__/;'` prints the same output as the example in your answer.

Answer (score 4):

## Brainfuck, 10 chars

Both previous Brainfuck solutions were *waaay* too long (16 and 11 chars) so here is a shorter one:

```
+[.->+<]>+
```

In the `n`-th block it prints out `2*n-1` characters (with codepoints from `2*n-1` to `1`)

Comment: This wouldn't work in standard brainfuck, only if the cells are unlimited-size. Actually, it wouldn't totally make sense then either. How do you output character code 1 trillion?

Answer (score 3):

## C, 87 bytes

```
#if!__COUNTER__
#include __FILE__
main(a){a=__COUNTER__-1;printf("%*d",a*a,0);}
#endif
```

This uses two magic macros. `__COUNTER__` is a macro that expands to `0` the first time it is used, `1` the second, etc. It is a compiler extension, but is available in both gcc, clang, and Visual Studio at least. `__FILE__` is the name of the source file. Including a file in C/C++ is literally the same as pasting it directly into your source code, so it was a little tricky to make use of.

It would still be possible to use this technique without `__COUNTER__`. In that case, the standard guard against using code twice could be used for the `#if` statement, and `__LINE__` could be used to count the number of characters needed.

Comment: This solution is not written in C, but rather a C dialect. Please correct the language name.

Comment: @FUZxxl Most code-golf answers are only designed to work in gcc, so I'm not sure why this would be an issue.

Comment: It isn't, but you should really declare that.

Comment: I'm confused. Why declare a non-issue? O_o

Comment: @corsiKa It's only a non-issue if you declare it. The C gcc speaks is not standard C.

Comment: @FUZxxl I would say the compiler listens to C, not speaks it :) It understands standard C perfectly well, but also knows some other words.

Comment: @feersum I don't care how you say it. A standard conforming compiler may reject your program for it violates the standard.

Answer (score 3):

## [Prelude](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Prelude), <s>18</s> 12 bytes

```
^1+(9!1-)#2+
```

This prints N<sup>2</sup> tabs. It assumes a standard-compliant interpreter which prints characters instead of numbers, so if you use [the Python interpreter](https://web.archive.org/web/20060504072747/http://z3.ca/~lament/prelude.py) you'll need to set `NUMERIC_OUTPUT` to `False`.

The idea is simply to use the top of the stack (which is initially 0) as `2(N-1)`, and print `2N-1` tabs, then increment the top of the stack by 2. Hence each repetition prints the next odd number of tabs.

Answer (score 3):

### Java - 59 / 44 (depending on requirements)

```
static String n="1";
static{System.out.print(n);n+="11";}//
```

Apparently we're allowed to assume code runs in a class.

If it can go inside a main method:

```
String n="1";
System.out.print(n);n+="11";//
```

Answer (score 2):

## Dyalog APL, <s>20</s> 19 bytes

A matrix based solution.

```
{⍺≢⍵:⍵⍪⍵,⍺⋄∊⍺}⍨⍪'a'
```

[Try it here](http://tryapl.org/). Returns a string of `N2` repetitions of `a`. Explanation by explosion for `N = 2`:

```
{⍺≢⍵:⍵⍪⍵,⍺⋄∊⍺}⍨⍪'a'{⍺≢⍵:⍵⍪⍵,⍺⋄∊⍺}⍨⍪'a'
                                  ⍪'a'  Wrap 'a' into a 1x1 matrix.
                'a'{            }⍨      Binary function: bind 'a' to ⍵ and the matrix to ⍺.
                    ⍺≢⍵:                The arguments are not identical,
                        ⍵⍪⍵,⍺           so add to the matrix 1 column and 1 row of 'a's.
               ⍪                        Identity function for a matrix.
{            }⍨                         Unary function: bind the matrix to both ⍵ and ⍺.
 ⍺≢⍵:                                   The arguments are identical,
           ∊⍺                           so flatten the matrix into the string 'aaaa'.
```

Answer (score 2):

### T-SQL 117

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#')IS NULL CREATE TABLE #(A INT)INSERT INTO # VALUES(1)SELECT REPLICATE('a',COUNT(*)*2-1)FROM #
```

Note the trailing space to ensure that the if condition is properly checked every time.

Uses the odd numbers approach. Not sure if there's a newline on select statements.

Not sure if there's a shorter way to create a table if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Kudos to you for an unusual language choice.

Answer (score 2):

### STATA 20

```
di _n($a)
gl a=$a+2
```

There is a trailing new line to make sure that the display (di) statement works.
First display the current number in $a newlines (and one additional from the default of display). Then add 2 to $a.

Uses the even numbers approach (i.e. odd numbers approach minus 1) with an extra newline every time.

Answer (score 2):

## PostScript, 35 chars

```
count dup 2 mul 1 add string print
```

Each pass "leaks" one thing on the stack, so `count` goes up by 1 each time.  Then it justs uses the sum of odd numbers trick.

The bytes output are all `\000` because that's the initial value of strings.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 72

```
putStr$let a="1";aputStr=(\n->take(n^2)$show n++cycle" ").(+1).read in a
```

### Explanation

The apply operator `$` acts as if you place surrounding parentheses around the rest of the line (there are exceptions to this, but it works in this case). `aputStr` is a function that takes a string with the format "abc    ...", where "abc" is the square root of the length of the string, including abc. It will parse the string as an integer, and return a string starting with abc+1 and having that length squared. Because of the `$` operator, this will get called recursively on "1" N times.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
:I,⇧
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCI6SSzih6ciLCIiLCIiXQ==)

-2 thanks to lyxal.

Note: output is  in spaces + newlines.

Comment: [I'm a little (a lot) late, but 5 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLIruKAujrCskkiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 8 bytes

```
*d*2Z~Z1
```

This relies on the fact that N<sup>2</sup> is equal to the sum of `N` odd numbers. Now Pyth auto prints an new line, so I have to just print `Z * 2` characters in each code where `Z` goes from `0` to `N - 1`.

**Code Expansion**:

```
*d               "Print d whose value is a space character"
  *2Z            "2 * Z times where Z's initial value is 0"
     ~Z1         "Increment the value of Z";
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/)

Answer (score 1):

## Golflua, 23 bytes

```
X=2+(X|-2)w(S.t("&",X))
```

outputs a combination of `&` and `\n` characters.

#### Equivalent Lua code

```
X = 2 + (X or -2)          -- initialize X to 0 the first time, add 2 ever other time

print(string.rep("&", X))
```

Each time the code snippet runs it produces 2 more characters of output than the last time, starting with 1 character. The `print` function appends a newline, so I initialize X to 0 instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

### ActionScript - 27 / 26 bytes

```
var n=""
trace(n);n+="11"//
```

or

```
var n=1
trace(n);n+="11"//
```

How it works:

```
var n=""
trace(n);n+="11"//var n=""
trace(n);n+="11"//
```

It simply comments out the first line. Note: `trace` adds a newline. Or maybe all the IDE's I use do that automatically.

Answer (score 0):

## GML, 27

```
a=''show_message(a)a+='xx'a
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/), 24 bytes

```
var s=""
echo s
s&="ss"#
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704LzN3wYKlpSVpuhY7yhKLFIptlZS4UpMz8hWKuYrVbJWKi5WUIdJQVTDVAA)

[Attempt This Online!Attempt This Online!Attempt This Online!Attempt This Online!Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704LzN3wYKlpSVpuhY3K8oSixSKbZWUuFKTM_IVirmK1WyViouVlGktDrEf6gyYcwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 12 bytes

```sh
<<<$n
n+=..
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BqsIwFET39ysGvZKEYrEuY/MV2QpSSvsMSNqXpG9h6LfXYhXe7nCGGeYZ74s1Yqnrmj35wpQlLYKs4Wx1pY/VTGNwPuEYsLPDFNpOg7P8LZSdd0T9EOAgc1WW59OsLpkAe3OFYbtS99c8IHqppODVCiVotcOUxikZlv0F7/EeWgF7sIRCTMGNESk07uH8D@LYtF38V8sb6NP7Hb4T4qNxiFff3psQNxTgLQHvN6B5eQE)

Same \$ n^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n 2k + 1 \$ as has been used elsewhere. The TIO test has to do some extra work because naively capturing the output in `$(f)` removes trailing newlines, and would output `0`, `3`, `8`, `15`, etc. Instead, we insert a `printf :` to add a character after the last newline, then `${output:0:-1}` to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 10 bytes

```
0ǰąŁ⁻√⁺²⑴ǰ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9weXT//zDHsMSFxYHigbviiJrigbrCsuKRtMew//8)

```
0              pushes 0
 ǰ             ǰoins stack with no delimiter
  ą            convert to ąrray of characters
   Ł           get the Łength
    ⁻          decrement
     √         square root
      ⁺        increment
       ²       square
        ⑴     array of (top of stack) 1s
          ǰ    ǰoin array with no delimiters (implicitly prints at end of code)
```