# Generate programs that print n times their length

Tags: code-golf, quine

Given a nonnegative integer `n`, your solution must output a program in your chosen language whose output has `n` times as many bytes as the outputted program.

### Rules

- You must specify the language and encoding of the programs your solution outputs, and you may not choose different languages or encodings for different inputs to your solution. The language of your output program may or may not be the same as the language of your solution.
- Your submission only needs to handle integers in your language's range, but please do not abuse this rule.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest submission in bytes wins.

### Example

Suppose `n` is 4. My solution then outputs `f_8`, a program which, in my (imaginary) language outputs `j3 1s+/2]!mz`. The program output has length 3 and its output has length 3 * 4 = 12, so the solution is correct for input 4.

Suppose instead that `n` is 1 and my program outputs `ffffpfpffp` (10 bytes). The program `ffffpfpffp` in my chosen language would have to produce an output of 10 * 1 = 10 bytes.

Comment: At the moment, this is pretty underspecified. Could you provide some examples?

Comment: I *think* I know what we're supposed to do, but every time I read the spec, I become less certain. *output some text that has n times as many bytes as the outputted program* seems to imply that we have to output a text and a program. *The character set and the language must be consistent for all integers.* Which "character set" is this referring to?

Comment: Nevermind, I actually *did* misunderstand, and so did all but one of the answers.

Comment: @Dennis It doesn't help that the title seems to contradict the body. Perhaps *Output a program that outputs n times its length* would be a better title, if I understand the challenge correctly (I'm not sure I do)

Comment: "*A program in your chosen language whose output has n times as many bytes as the outputted program*". On what input? I would guess given no input, but that should be explicit.

Comment: Can I use HQ9+ as the output language? (I think consensus allows that now) if so then a 3-byte solution would be trivial.

Comment: What happens if the two languages use different code pages?

Comment: Can we take `n` as a string?

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 38 bytes

```js
n=>`(x="${n}")=>(x+1/7+1e9).repeat(x)`
```

#### Demo

```js
let f =

n=>`(x="${n}")=>(x+1/7+1e9).repeat(x)`

function update() {
  let n = I.value,
      func = f(n),
      res = eval(func)();
  O.innerText =
    'n = ' + n + '\n\n' +
    'Function (' + func.length + ' bytes):\n' + func + '\n\n' +
    'Function output (' + res.length + ' bytes):\n' + res;
}
update()
```

```html
<input type=range id=I min=0 max=100 oninput="update()">
<pre id=O>
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
;“DL+8×x@⁶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/6UcMcFx9ti8PTKxweNW77//@/oREA)

For input `12`, it outputs `12DL+8×x@⁶`, which outputs 120 spaces. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/QyMVH2@Lw9AqHR43b/v8HAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tio-transpilers), 348 bytes

```
--[>+<++++++]>>--[>+<++++++]>++[-<+>]----[>+<----]>---[-<+>]----[>+<----]>-[-<+>]-[>+<---]>++++++[-<+>]-[>+<---]>++++++++[-<+>]--[>+<++++++]>+++[-<+>]<[<],[->.<]>>>>>.<<<.>>.<<<.>>>.<<<.>>>.<<<.>>...>>>.<<....<<.>>>.<<..<<.>>>..<<.......>>>>.<<<..<<.>.....>>>.<<.>>.>>.<<<<<.>>>>.<<.<<.>>.>.<<<.>>.<<<.>>...<<.>>>..>>.<<.>.<<<.>.<<.>>>.>>.<<<..>>>.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7RCoAwCEXf@xXTLxB/ZOyhgiCCHoK@f83pNhb5op676916L8e1P9uZEmIQYCgVRcYVICCDRETj2qPo8ocdOlG31j/tl8c8xxw4zgGFOP8pFzEztfbtRL7kgZrSRhfslXmKVJG98/PmKczxmN0TyJ0mVFoDdE5pegE) Or see the [Ungolfed version](https://tio.run/##lVLLTsMwELzvV@wRFGKJl7hYlhBwqISgqsqpyiFN3bQ0saPEQfx9WMcpsUUqYA9ONLOezOxmXad7tW2zQ9fF8UpEPOorEVgVbQMCQjSKsNwrIlYxj0RCrOPtMxF0YCGbUyzmtUyNrL/pgbOytlBXUp0iic4K3chRO/QV4UabgeQAK55grtFoXMutriWanXSRAC5wr6rWUFMsGPVZGD/xrEfPAR7f5s@zh/vl6wJA2GLOGeecDfEtdkzTw25a/4QZY/28xsP1uqAwX8xelk9kIt28t41ByoFVrfM6LalZ5WYHJMesyqBOKW7Adzla9z8FgbXx9uiRuXI6pHoHwnPGT8qFt24BalnqD4mZLtpS4SWEno6ZB8S@2C1yHozaG8lGZqQolTkqXvUj8J1PbIhcVEWaBTb@vtOJLf0yP8@wn/469DplgU3oT8nSr71OswP8WIU3rK6DLw) (i.e. what I had to work with)

---

#### Disclaimer

I spent more time making this than I thought was humanly possible. I'd like to thank my girlfriend for allowing me to ditch her to work on this; as well as [my savior](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_constants).

#### How does it even work?

No clue.

#### *How* does it work?

All outputs have a trailing snippet of code that are all the same:

```
[->+>+>+<<<]>>>>-[<<+>>-------]<<+-----[<[.-]>->[->+<<<+>>]>[-<+>]<<]
```

Let's split it into three parts called `a,b,c`

```
a : [->+>+>+<<<]>>>>               THE DUPLICATOR
b : -[<<+>>-------]<<+-----        THE ADJUSTER
c : [<[.-]>->[->+<<<+>>]>[-<+>]<<] THE PRINTER
```

The input `i` is simply tacked on to the front in unary:

```
iabc
```

*(e.g; if the input was 10, then `i = '++++++++++'`)*

**The Duplicator**
 - Splits the input into two identical numbers `m, n`, equivalent to the input

**The Adjuster**
 - Adjusts `n` such that it equals the length of the program

**The Printer**
 - Prints `m*n` ASCII characters

---

*Note that the input in the example is a `newline`, which as an ASCII value of 10, therefore the input is `10`. If you want to test other small numbers, replace the `,` with however many `+`'s you desire.*

Answer (score 2):

## [Cheddar](https://cheddar.vihan.org), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
(*)&" "*9
```

An awkward Proton polyglot >_<

Comment: +1 for Proton polyglot with Cheddar to show the inspiration :D

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 55 bytes

```hs
f n=(++)<*>show$"main=putStr$[1.."++show n++"*2]>>'#':"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hz1ZDW1vTRsuuOCO/XEUpNzEzz7agtCS4pEgl2lBPT0lbGyShkKetraRlFGtnp66sbqX0H6RMwVYBolBBRSFNwZBLVxddsyFCBx6p/wA) Example usage: `f 1` yields the following 54 bytes program:

```hs
main=putStr$[1..1*2]>>'#':"main=putStr$[1..1*2]>>'#':"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM8@2oLQkuKRIJdpQT89QyyjWzk5dWd1KCY/U//8A)
 which produces the following 54 byte output:

```hs
#main=putStr$[1..1*2]>>'#':#main=putStr$[1..1*2]>>'#':
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) -> HQ9+, 11 bytes

```python
'Q'.__mul__
```

It had to be done

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fpmCrEPNfPVBdLz4@tzQnPv5/QVFmXolGmoappuZ/AA)

Comment: Where can I test HQ?

Comment: Well, `Q` just prints its own source code. You can test that here: http://hq9plus.alwaysdata.net. This was never supposed to be a serious entry

Comment: This doesn't work. If I input `1`, then you output `Q`, which in turn outputs `Q`. `Q` has length `1`, but your code has length `11`.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere 'whose output has n times as many bytes as the outputted program.' (not the submitted program)

Comment: @michi7x7 Ok, but the interpreter you linked outputs (for `QQ`) `QQ\nQQ`, which is `5` bytes, not `4`.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere this does not: https://almnet.de/esolang/hq9plus.php (The language specification only states "Prints the entire text of the source code file")

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>175</s> 174 bytes

```java
interface M{static void main(String[]a){System.out.printf("interface M{static void main(String[]a){int i=(88+%s)*%s;for(;i-->0;System.out.print(0));}}",a[0].length(),a[0]);}}
```

**Examples:**

[`n=1` outputs](https://tio.run/##jYyxCoMwFEV/JQhC0jYh3YRQ/6CTozg8NNpnayLJq1DEb09tx04dz@HcO8IC0s/Wjd09JXRkQw@tZdc1EhC2bPHYsQnQ8YoCuqFuQKzVK5KdlH@SmndJPc/@ne4dwwsvimMexSGPpveBG5Sy1Ob3lmshzLZlJ6h1ox7WDXTj4ksfn1I6vwE):

```java
interface M{static void main(String[]a){int i=(88+1)*1;for(;i-->0;System.out.print(0));}}
```

(length=89) [which outputs 89 zeroes](https://tio.run/##DcqxCoAgEADQX3HUwsgtkPqDpsZoOMrijDTsCkL6dvPNz8ID0p/G2WVPCR2ZsMJsWB8vAsKZPR4XdgA6PlBAt40TiJgfw5Y3TalEofTqA9coZVfr4b3IHJW/qTpzJ14Lob8vpR8):

```java
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

---

[`n=10` outputs](https://tio.run/##jYyxCoMwFEV/JQhC0jYh3YRQ/6CTozg8NNpnayLJq1DEb09tx04dz@HcO8IC0s/Wjd09JXRkQw@tZdc1EhC2bPHYsQnQ8YoCuqFuQKzVK5KdlH@SmndJPc/@ne4dwwsvimMexSGPpveBG5Sy1Ob3lmshzLZlJ6h1ox7WDXTj4ksfn1I66zc):

```java
interface M{static void main(String[]a){int i=(88+2)*10;for(;i-->0;System.out.print(0));}}
```

(length=90) [which outputs 900 zeroes](https://tio.run/##DcqxCoAgEADQX3HUwrCmQOoPmhqj4TCLK9KwKwjp2603vxVukP6wbp22lNCRDTMYy7p4EhAadnuc2A7oeE8B3TKMIOL/GDa8rvNKZKXSsw9co5St0v1zkt0Lf1Fx/J@4EkK/b0of):

```java
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

---

[`n=100` outputs](https://tio.run/##jYyxCoMwFEV/JQhC0jYh3YRQ/6CTozg8NNpnayLJq1DEb09tx04dz@HcO8IC0s/Wjd09JXRkQw@tZdc1EhC2bPHYsQnQ8YoCuqFuQKzVK5KdlH@SmndJPc/@ne4dwwsvimMexSGPpveBG5Sy1Ob3lmshzLZlJ6h1ox7WDXTj4ksfn1I6a/0G):

```java
interface M{static void main(String[]a){int i=(88+3)*100;for(;i-->0;System.out.print(0));}}
```

(length=91) [which outputs 9100 zeroes](https://tio.run/##DcuxCoAgEADQX3HUwjBaAqk/aGqMhsMsrkjDriCkb7f291a4QfrDunXaUkJHNsxgLOviSUBo2O1xYjug4z0FdMswgoi/Y9jwus4rkZVK6dkHrlHKVun@Ocnuhb@oOP5AXAmh3zelDw):

```java
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

**Explanation:**

```java
interface M{                                // Class:
  static void main(String[]a){              //  Mandatory main method
    System.out.printf("interface M{static void main(String[]a){
                                            //   Print a new program with:
      int i=(88+%s)*%s;                     //    Integer containing (88*A)+B
      for(;i-->0;System.out.print(0));}}",  //    And print that many zeroes
        a[0].length(),                      //     Where A is the length of the number
                                            //     (0-9 = 1; 10-99 = 2; 100-999 = 3; etc.)
        a[0]);}}                            //     and B is the number itself
```

Answer (score 0):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), <s>7</s> 5 bytes

```
«•.*
```

*With a trailing space*

### Explained

```
«•.* 
«    # Yield a function from the remaining string.
 •.  # Append a space and stringify, which builds the original program (Because stringifying a function removes noops, which spaces are)
   * # Repeat the implicit input times.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6///Q6kcNi/S0FP7//28KAA)

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, <s>8</s> 13 bytes

```
q_,S\" 8+*S*"
```

[Try it Online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q_%2CS%5C%22%208%2B*S*%22&input=100)

The generated program outputs spaces so it's kind of hard to tell.

Comment: I think this is the only answer that interprets the part about outputting a program that outputs a text correctly, but the ratio is off if the input has more than one digit.

Comment: Oh yeah, duh.,,

Answer (score 0):

## [Ly](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Ly), 29 bytes

```
"\"9>("&onu")[<&s&ol>1-]<;"&o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/18pRsnSTkNJLT@vVEkz2katWC0/x85QN9bGGij2/7@hAQA) <s>(does not work currently due to a pre-processing bug)</s> All good!

Answer (score 0):

## Python → TECO, 20 bytes

The answer is in Python while the generated code is in TECO. The Python is a function returning `VV12345\VV` repeated *n* times. See [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/45380/30688) for an explanation of the TECO.

```
'VV12345\VV'.__mul__
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 47+1 bytes

```php
<?="<?=str_pad(_,",strlen($argn)+18,"*$argn);";
```

prints one underscore followed by spaces.
Run as pipe with `-F`; run outputted program with `-f` or `-F`.

This would fail for input with more than 64 digits,
which is far higher than `PHP_INT_MAX` (at this time).

However, it fails for input larger than `PHP_INT_MAX`-18 ... does it still qualify?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino: This will fail for input larger than `PHP_INT_MAX`-18. Does that disqualify?

Comment: Nah, I'll say that's fine :)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP → Python 2, 40+1 bytes

```php
print "A"*<?=13+strlen($argn),"*",$argn;
```

prints a Python program that prints repeated `A`s. Run as pipe with `-F`.

Answer (score 0):

### Batch → Charcoal, 22 bytes

I'm not sure which encoding I should be using, since these are bytes. Here are the bytes interpreted as Windows-1252:

```
@set/p=Á%1ñªÉñ«Ìñ¹<nul
```

The same bytes as PC-850:

```
@set/p=┴%1±¬╔±½╠±╣<nul
```

The same bytes in Charcoal's code page:

```
@set/p=Ａ%1θ×Ｉθ⁺Ｌθ⁹<nul
```

The resulting Charcoal program is `Plus(Length(Cast(n)), 9)` bytes long:

```
Ａ       Assign
 %1      (String representation of n)
   θ      To variable q
        Implicitly print a number of `-`s equal to:
×        Product of:
 Ｉθ       Cast of q to integer
 ⁺        Sum of:
  Ｌθ       Length of q
  ⁹        Integer constant 9
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES8), <s>43</s> <s>41</s> 39 bytes

```js
n=>`f=_=>"".padEnd(${n}*(88+f).length)`
```

---

### Test it

The output of the generated function is a string of spaces which are replaced with `*`s in this Snippet.

```js
g=
n=>`f=_=>"".padEnd(${n}*(88+f).length)`

o.innerText=(h=n=>`Function: ${x=g(n)}\nLength:   ${x.length}\nOutput:   "${x=eval(x)().replace(/./g,"*")}"\nLength:   `+x.length)(i.value=10);oninput=_=>o.innerText=h(+i.value)
```

```html
<input id=i type=number><pre id=o>
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Recursiva](https://github.com/officialaimm/recursiva), <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
++"*"V*15a'"*"'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pNLi0qzixL/P9fW1tJSylMy9A0UR3IUP//3wgA)

This for input of `n=2` prints:

```
*30"*"
```

which outputs 30 `*`.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pNLi0qzixL/P9fy9hASUvp/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 46 bytes

```r
function(n)sprintf("cat(rep('a',%d*23),'')",n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcvLCYAwDADQu1OIIE2kHtSr7uAKpaYiSFpi/GxfETw/nuRQjm2Zw8let8jAeCTZWANU3ikIJTDO2Hpp@gGtMVhZxsx0zxLXrwbosKDL7ZCcHARKj06/I@YX)

Anonymous function that returns the string

```r
cat(rep('a',n*23),'')
```

Which prints `a` (that's `a` followed by a space) 23 times `n` times. I needed the `''` because otherwise `cat` wouldn't print the last space character.

Answer (score 0):

## C, 94 bytes

```
main(int c,char**a){if(c>1){c=atoi(a[1]);if(c>0&&c<0xFFFFFF){c*=94;while(c--)printf("r");}}}
```

this would be 94 bytes include the last \n that stadard C says it should be written.
return as 'r' characters as the (lenght of the program) * (argument of the program)
if the program argument not exist or it is <=0 or it is >0xFFFFF print nothing
example

```
C:\>nameProg.exe 1
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
```

Answer (score 0):

### MATLAB (63 bytes)

```
a=@(n)['repmat(''a'',1,',num2str(n*(15+numel(num2str(n)))),')']
```

For example:

```
>> a(5)

ans =

repmat('a',1,80)
```

and:

```
>> repmat('a',1,80)

ans =

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```